# Updating a JFrame with the component from another method

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I am trying to add JPanel p4 to the JFrame but it doesn't seemed to work.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Class4 {

    public static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public JFrame f = new JFrame("Love Test");

    public void mainMethod(int event){

        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(500,200);     
        f.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        if(event == 0){


            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

            JPanel p = new JPanel();
            p.setLayout(new BoxLayout(p,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
            p.setBounds(150, 0, 500, 75);
            p.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350,75));
            JTextField boy = new JTextField();
            boy.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(200,40));
            JTextField girl = new JTextField();
            girl.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(200,40));
            p.add(boy);
            p.add(girl);
            gbc.insets = new Insets(-90,310,0,0);
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            f.add(p,gbc);

            JPanel p3 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            p3.setBounds(0, 0, 150, 75);
            p.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,75));
            Class5 c5o = new Class5();
            c5o.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,75));
            p3.add(c5o);
            gbc.insets = new Insets(0,0,90,330);
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            f.add(p3,gbc);

            JPanel p2 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
            Class7 c7o = new Class7();
            p2.add(c7o);
            p2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,40));
            gbc.insets = new Insets(0,0,-20,0);
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            f.add(p2,gbc);

            f.setVisible(true);


        }

        if(event == 5){

            addLove();

        }

    }
    public void addLove(){

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        JPanel p4 = new JPanel();
        p4.setBounds(0,120,500,55);
        Class2 c2o = new Class2();
        Dimension d2 = new Dimension(500,55);
        c2o.setPreferredSize(d2);
        p4.setPreferredSize(d2);
        p4.add(c2o);
        gbc.insets = new Insets(0,0,-130,0);
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        f.add(p4,gbc);

        f.invalidate();
        f.validate();
        f.repaint();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Test");
    }


}
```

However, if I twisted the code to what is shown below, JPanel p4 will be added to the JFrame.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Class4 {

    public static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public JFrame f = new JFrame("Love Test");

    public void mainMethod(int event){

        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(500,200);     
        f.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        if(event == 0){


            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

            JPanel p = new JPanel();
            p.setLayout(new BoxLayout(p,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
            p.setBounds(150, 0, 500, 75);
            p.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350,75));
            JTextField boy = new JTextField();
            boy.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(200,40));
            JTextField girl = new JTextField();
            girl.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(200,40));
            p.add(boy);
            p.add(girl);
            gbc.insets = new Insets(-90,310,0,0);
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            f.add(p,gbc);

            JPanel p3 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            p3.setBounds(0, 0, 150, 75);
            p.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,75));
            Class5 c5o = new Class5();
            c5o.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,75));
            p3.add(c5o);
            gbc.insets = new Insets(0,0,90,330);
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            f.add(p3,gbc);

            JPanel p2 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
            Class7 c7o = new Class7();
            p2.add(c7o);
            p2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,40));
            gbc.insets = new Insets(0,0,-20,0);
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            f.add(p2,gbc);

            f.setVisible(true);

            JPanel p4 = new JPanel();
            p4.setBounds(0,120,500,55);
            Class2 c2o = new Class2();
            Dimension d2 = new Dimension(500,55);
            c2o.setPreferredSize(d2);
            p4.setPreferredSize(d2);
            p4.add(c2o);
            gbc.insets = new Insets(0,0,-130,0);
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            f.add(p4,gbc);

            f.invalidate();
            f.validate();
            f.repaint();
        }

        if(event == 5){

            addLove();

        }

    }
    public void addLove(){



        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Test");
    }


}
```

But the JPanel will shown immediately once I run the code. I only want the JPanel to show up after an event(pressing the button). All help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Try to use the same `GridBagConstraints gbc` in both method.

Comment: Don't add to the jframe, add to its container `(f.getContentPane().add(...))` and set the layoutmanager of the contentpane. Will save you headache like this.

Comment: What's the value of `event`? It can't be both `0` and `5`.

Comment: it is changed in another class

Comment: How about put `f.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());` in `if(event==0){`?

Comment: It threw an exception @johnchen902

Comment: What exception? Where did you put `setLayout`? At the begin or end of `if`?

Comment: at the beginning. the exception is 'cannot add to layout: constraint must be a string (or null)' @johnchen902

Comment: I ran the code and it performed the same whether twisted or not: test code: http://ideone.com/jLbqv7 Also I cannot figure out why exception...